# Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : final tuning parameters could not be determined

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, kaggle

I am very new at machine learning and am attempting the [forest cover prediction competition on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/forest-cover-type-prediction), but I am getting hung up pretty early on. I get the following error when I run the code below.

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

```
# Load the libraries
library(ggplot2); library(caret); library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
library(pROC)
library(Amelia)

set.seed(1234)

# Load the forest cover dataset from the csv file
rawdata <- read.csv("train.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)
#this data won't be used in model evaluation. It will only be used for the submission.
test <- read.csv("test.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)

########################
### DATA PREPARATION ###
########################

#create a training and test set for building and evaluating the model
samples <- createDataPartition(rawdata$Cover_Type, p = 0.5,list = FALSE)
data.train <- rawdata[samples, ]
data.test <- rawdata[-samples, ]

model1 <- train(as.factor(Cover_Type) ~ Elevation + Aspect + Slope + Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology, 
                data = data.train, 
                method = "rf", prox = "TRUE")
```

Comment: Show us the first few warnings reported by `warnings()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should work:

```
model1 <- train(as.factor(Cover_Type) ~ Elevation + Aspect + Slope + Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology,
                          data = data.train,
                          method = "rf", tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 3))
```

Its always better to specify the `tuneGrid` parameter which is a data frame with possible tuning values. Look at `?randomForest` and `?train` for more information. `rf` has only one tuning parameter `mtry`, which controls the number of features selected for each tree.

You can also run `modelLookup` to get a list of tuning parameters for each model

```
> modelLookup("rf")
#  model parameter                         label forReg forClass probModel
#1    rf      mtry #Randomly Selected Predictors   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
```

Comment: This is helpful (+1) but I have this problem when running `train` with `method  = "parRF"`  and it persists even when I use `tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 3)` whereas I had no errors with `method = "rf"`

Answer (score 4):

I too am doing Kaggle competitions and have been using the 'caret' package to help with choosing the 'best' model parameters. After getting many of these errors I looked into the scripting behind the scenes and discovered a call to a function called 'class2ind' which does not exist (at least anywhere I know). I finally found another function called 'class.ind' which is in the 'nnet' package. I decided to just try and create a local function called 'class2ind' and pop in the code from the 'class.ind' function. And low and behold it worked!

```
# fix for caret
class2ind <- function(cl)
{
        n <- length(cl)
        cl <- as.factor(cl)
        x <- matrix(0, n, length(levels(cl)) )
        x[(1:n) + n*(unclass(cl)-1)] <- 1
        dimnames(x) <- list(names(cl), levels(cl))
        x
}
```