# Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : final tuning parameters could not be determined

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to predict outcome using `caret` in R. When I am trying to train the model, I am getting the error:

> Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
>     final tuning parameters could not be determined

I have tried other classification methods too with their respective `tuneGrid` data frames. I have also tried the solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683749/error-in-train-defaultx-y-weights-w-final-tuning-parameters-could-n) but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
d <- read.csv("train.csv")
new <- d[1:50,-1]
library(caret)

modfit <- train(target~., method="rf", data=new)

Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

modfit<- train(target~., data= new, method= "rf", tuneGrid= data.frame(mtry=3))

Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: There were 27 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Row one was ID and so was removed.

Comment: The data file is a kaggle competition file.
https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/download/train.csv.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the dataset, and you have two issues here:

Firstly, since you're doing classification, it's best to specify that target is a factor. I.e.,

```
modfit <- train(as.factor(target)~., method="rf", data=new)
```

Secondly, the first 50 rows of the dataset only have class_1. You need at least two different classes. If you really only want to work with 50 rows you can take a random sample.

```
new = d[sample(1:nrow(d), size = 50), ].
```

Calling `warnings()` can be very useful for debugging in these situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh. Will keep this in mind in future.